# how to convert a hashmap of list into a single list in Java 8?

Tags: java, dictionary, streaming, flatmap

I am completely new to java 8 and i am a bit unclear on how to proceed.
i have a Map `<String, List<value>>` in Java 7, i would just use for loop on the keys and collect the List into a single list.

however, i want to be able to do this in 8. 
what i have is:

```
List<Value> newList = resultMap.entrySet().stream()
                       .flatMap( e -> e.getValue().stream())
                       .map( // get the value in the list)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

However, in this case, i would not be able to know the key from the hashmap which the value belongs to.

How can i get the value of the key for the `hashmap` while doing the above?

Comment: What does the code look like in for loop? I want to know how do you do with the key, as you are not putting it in the resulting list.

Comment: For they keys, you would use `keySet` instead of `entrySet`; please clarify what type `resultMap` has and what you expect to be in `newList`.

Comment: `List values = map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @CardinalSystem The OP said the Map's type should be something like `Map<?, List<Value>>` so you can't directly use `Collectors.toList()` on the Map's values.

Comment: You can't get back the key after you've discarded it.  Your `flatMap` lambda has to preserve whatever information you want later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Map<Key, List<Value>> map = ...;

List<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> list =
    map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> {
          return e.getValue().stream()
              .map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), v));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This creates an entry for each value in each sublist, where the key is the corresponding key for the list that value came from.